# Use nginx to serve static pages with custom URLs

Tags: url, nginx

I have a bunch of static html pages (everything is fixed on the page, including all html, css and javascript), and want to serve them using `nginx`.

However, I want users to access these static pages using the following URL pattern:

`www.example.com/public/static/filename?para=blah`

where `public/static/filename` is mapped to `/home/www/example/public/static/filename.html` on the server, but still retain the `?para=blah` part in the address bar of user's browser. The purpose of having the extra `?para=blah` bit in the end is that, once the static `filename.html` page is loaded, the javascript inside the page will strip off `blah` and perform some logic based on it.

Is it possible to do this efficiently using some nginx configs?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs on [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files), that is probably what you need.

Something along the lines of

```
location /public/static/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.html?&$args;
}
```

Just freewheeling.

**edit**: don't forget to check the solution against the [nginx pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls)